# Email custom photo album images

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I created custom photo album for capturing photos. And i invoked this album inside my app. After clicking button the album is invoked. But i can't share this image to mail. I used `MFMailComposeViewController` for sending.

code:

```
photopick= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [photopick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [photopick setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 50)];

    [photopick addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlbum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:photopick];

-(void)showAlbum:(id)sender{

    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

   // imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;


    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    //release picker
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //set image

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];




    //  newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [newImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

    //  [newImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];



    [self.view addSubview:newImage];

    // [newImage release];


    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

After picking image i have other button to send newImage (album image) to mail:

```
-(void)send:(id)sender{

MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [picker setSubject:@"My image"];

        UIImage *roboPic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RobotWithPencil.jpg"];

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(roboPic, 1);
        [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"RobotWithPencil.jpg"];




        NSString *emailBody = @"This is a cool image of a robot I found.  Check it out!";
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

But how can i set album image to inside  `MFMailComposeViewController`. Some docs mentioned used `[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];` Here i don't have imageName. I have images from album

Comment: save image in docement directory

Comment: My requirement is save image to custom album and to share

Comment: use your custom album path and create image reference using that path and use NSData for attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following link

[MFMail](https://github.com/aporat/iTellAFriend)

you can set Multiple images in Messagebody using for loop.

set your message body with this function

```
     - (NSString *)messageBody
     {
         // if we couldn't fetch the app information, use a simple fallback template
         if (self.applicationSellerName==nil) {
             // Fill out the email body text
             NSMutableString *emailBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div> \n"
                                  "<p style=\"font:17px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\">%@</p> \n"
                                  "<h1 style=\"font:bold 16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"%@\">%@</a></h1> \n"
                                  "<br> \n"
                                  "<table align=\"center\"> \n"
                                  "<tbody> \n"
                                  "<tr> \n"
                                  "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"center\"> \n"
                                  "<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:11px;color:#696969;font-weight:bold\"> \n"
                                  "</td> \n"
                                  "</tr> \n"
                                  "<tr> \n"
                                  "<td align=\"left\"> \n"
                                  "<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:11px;color:#696969\"> \n"
                                  "Please note that you have not been added to any email lists. \n"
                                  "</span> \n"
                                  "</td> \n"
                                  "</tr> \n"
                                  "</tbody> \n"
                                  "</table> \n"
                                  "</div>",
                                  self.message,
                                  [self.appStoreURL absoluteString],
                                  self.applicationName
                                  ];

             return emailBody;

         }
```